# Clear contents of one cell when another is changed - for multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched for an answer on this and cannot find anything specific to my needs. I am creating a sheet that will have multiple rows that need to have the same functionality. For example, in Row 2 - I need the contents of D2:F2 to clear if the value in B2 is changed.

I found a VBA code that works great for that one instance. However, I also need that same functionality in Row 6, Row 10, Row 14, etc. - every 4th row until row 118 - 30 in total.

Each row needs to be exclusive. If I change the value in B2, I don't want it to clear out the values in other rows - only row 2. And if I change the value in B6, I only want the values to change in row 6...and so on.

This is the code I am using for B2, but I wasn't sure if it can be modified for more rows or if I need an entirely different code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("D2:F2").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Please advise - Thank you!

Comment: What is currently in cells `D2:F2`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MOD`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row > 118 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row Mod 4 = 2 And Not Intersect(Target, Cells(Target.Row, 2)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("D" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: ( @NicholasF. - If mine, or ShaiRado's, solution worked for you, you can flag as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post (below the down arrow) )

Answer (score 1):

First limit the `Target.Row` between 2 and 118.

Second, use `Mod` to check only 4th row.

Try something like the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row >= 2 And Target.Row <= 118 Then
    If (Target.Row + 2) Mod 4 = 0 Then
        If Target.Column = 2 Then
            Target.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 3).ClearContents
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: From a runtime point of view, any idea if it's "quicker" to do `If Target.Row > 118 Then Exit Sub` over `If Target.Row <= 118 Then ...`?  Let's assume though that the part to run is say 100 lines.  For VBA, is it just as quick to exit the sub immediately, as it is to skip down over all the code to the `End If // End Sub`?

Comment: @BruceWayne it depends, if you want to see how fast it clears, than mine is 1 row less, yours first checks if it outside the range. But, it's really not noticeable